# IE 11 Placeholder text missing

Tags: angularjs, html, placeholder

I'm having an issue with placeholder text not appearing in IE 11 when utilizing AngularJS. It shows up on every other browser and I haven't modified any CSS to change the appearance of it. I have even disabled all stylesheets and still can't get them to appear. See image below.

[image]

If I visit other sites that utilize placeholders within input fields - I have no issues. I'm a bit stumped in terms of resolving the issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // IE workaround to show placeholder
    $(element).placeholder();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems I found my issue and also have a solution to follow up. Prior to this I was having compatibility issues with Angular running in specific version of IE and had force compatibility to IE 9 inserting this in the head of my HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

I then proceeded to utilize this angular directive https://github.com/cvn/angular-shims-placeholder. It didn't work right off the bat but after scratching my head some more, I realized it may be a caching issue and upon clearing it out, I now have placeholders within my inputs in IE!